# Linker error for global variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, global-variables, linker-errors

I'm making a small, simple application, so I decided to use global variables over Singletons. I'm also only using one.

My app pulls an int from a small preference file, and that is set to the global variable as an NSInteger. The global variable may be changed while the app is running.

AppController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

extern NSInteger preferenceNumber;

@interface ....
```

App Controller.m

```
-(void)someMethod {
    ...
    //fileContents is a string containing the int that is inside the file
    preferenceNumber = [fileContents intValue]
    ...
}
```

The Linker Errors (2):
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  **"_preferenceNumber", referenced from:**
      -[AppController someMethod1] in AppController.o
      -[AppController someMethod2:] in AppController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

The bolded parts are the two errors.

What is causing this? What is the simplest, best way to solve it?

Comment: Where is the definition for `preferenceNumber`?

Comment: @Sebastian Sorry, it was in there I had just forgotten to turn it into code. Its in App Controller.m I edited it back in

Comment: There still isn't a definition, only a declaration of `preferenceNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one line in your implementation class:-

```
AppContollr.m


@implementation AppContoller
NSInteger preferenceNumber;
```